# Jenkins threaded (parent child) jobs

Tags: jenkins

We are trying to create some sanity tests for our Jenkins build environment. We want to create one master job that executes multiple subsequent jobs (these jobs will actually test the environment). The master job should fail if any of sub jobs fail. The threaded steps in IBM BuildForge does exactly like this. What's the best way to implement this in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Parametrized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

With it you can add substeps named `Trigger/call builds on other projects` which will fail your master job if they fail themselves.

[image]

Comment: Which version of the Parameterized Trigger Plugin are you using since i could not find the checkbox for "Block until trigerred projects finish their builds" in version 2.30

Comment: this seems to be working/available for MultiJob Projects, and not for BuildFlow Types

Answer (score 0):

Because this sanity test has to be layered,e.g. first check if all slaves are online, then check if integration to other tools such GitHub is ok, then run some sample build such as MSBuild. I found Multijob plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin), is easier to implement this structure.